# Android custom Carousel Image layout

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I want to implement the following type image scroll view, which will populate dynamically (imageViews).
[image]

I have already tried with  [this](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/830)

But it could not able to give the desired UI effect.
Can any body help me how could this can be achieved.

Comment: Use view pager and fragments, each fragment can contain image and textview, ez pz

Comment: If I do it using view pager, then will i able to set the three page to display at a time and the child views behind the focused view?

Comment: Yes, using custom page transformer

Comment: @MarkoNiciforovic do you have any example to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ViewPager** and set **pageTransform animation** like:

```
mPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
```

for more detail: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: If I do it using view pager, then will i able to set the three page to display at a time and the child views behind the focused view?

Comment: you can use setPageMargin() of ViewPager with negative value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try out carousel view here :

In Gradle: compile 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.4'
In XML:

```
 <com.synnapps.carouselview.CarouselView
    android:id="@+id/carouselView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:fillColor="#FFFFFFFF"
    app:pageColor="#00000000"
    app:radius="6dp"
    app:slideInterval="3000"
    app:strokeColor="#FF777777"
    app:strokeWidth="1dp"/>
```

In class:

```
public class SampleCarouselViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

CarouselView carouselView;

int[] sampleImages = {R.drawable.image_1, R.drawable.image_2, R.drawable.image_3, R.drawable.image_4, R.drawable.image_5};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample_carousel_view);

    carouselView = (CarouselView) findViewById(R.id.carouselView);
    carouselView.setPageCount(sampleImages.length);

    carouselView.setImageListener(imageListener);
}

ImageListener imageListener = new ImageListener() {
    @Override
    public void setImageForPosition(int position, ImageView imageView) {
        imageView.setImageResource(sampleImages[position]);
    }
};
```

}

Doc: https://github.com/sayyam/carouselview